# Symfony 4, role checking from annotation, is it possible to call a user role validate function?

Tags: symfony, annotations, symfony4, symfony-security

With Symfony (I learn from Symfony 4), I want allow access to a custom controller depending of the role of the connected user.

In the annotations , I see I can manage the role access with :

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
public function hello($name)
{
...
```

Is it possible to call a function in the annotation like this ?

```
/**
 * @Security("my_verification_function")
 */
public function hello($name)
{
...
}
...
private function verification_function(){
   //some process
   if (...) 
     return true; // the user can access to the page
   else ... 
     return false; // the user can't access to the page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://matthiasnoback.nl/2011/12/symfony2-doctrine-common-creating-powerful-annotations/) is a good example of using Symfony with Doctrine Common in order to create powerful annotations.